# Redirection of Old Application to New Application URL in Wildfly 8.1

Tags: java, .htaccess, redirect, wildfly, wildfly-8

We have an Application "AppA" which is running at following url in Wildfly 8.1 for example with context /appa
Application A URL: www.appa.xyz.com/appa (Landing Page)

The new application which we have rewritten using Application "AppA" that is Application AppB with context /appb has following URL in Widlfly 8.1 Server where application AppA is deployed.
Application B URL: www.appb.xyz.com/appb (Landing Page)

Now we would like to remove the old application "A" but also want the old url(www.appa.xyz.com/appa ) to redirect to new URL(www.appb.xyz.com/appb) using Widfly 8.1 only (We don't want to install Apache or anything else).

How can this be done ?

Comment: Can you still keep a small webapp available in "appa"?  A JSP in "appa" could send a redirect if you're not worried about sub-paths or a Filter could do a complete job if you want subpaths and query parameters.